# Javascript document.domain: Chrome and Firefox return different

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

In the case of internationalized domain name, Chrome and Firefox return different result for the same domain.

Firefox

```
> document.domain
"веб-коннект.рф"
```

Chrome

```
> document.domain
"xn----9sbcmc3abwai2c.xn--p1ai"
```

Same behavior for `window.location.hostname`

Chrome return domain name in punycode.
Is the any way to get domain name in punycode in Firefox or, get readable domain name in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like [`punycode.js`](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/blob/master/punycode.min.js) and check if the code is in punycode, decode it and check:

```js
if (document.domain.indexOf("xn----") < 0)
  document.domain = punycode.encode(document.domain);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/master/punycode.min.js"></script>
```